# Iphone app compatibility question

Tags: iphone, version, compatibility

I have an app used iphone4's new feature (MFMessageComposeViewController). because this class does not exist in iphone3, I have to use a workaround method (old code) to do the thing.

```
if ([self isVersion4]){ use new code } else { use old code }
```

I compiled my app in iphone4 SDK and it runs well.
I want to know if the app cound run well in iphone3.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to test it on iOS 3.x. Unfortunately, last time I looked, there was no way around this.